# Why isn't the following counter increasing?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

As you can see I'm creating a counter in the `createContents` and using it with the data passed to `convertToHTML`:

```
function createContents(text, orig) {
  if (orig.match(/^#{2}\s/)) {
    let index = 1
      , headingIndex = `item-${index++}`
      , headingText = `${text.replace(/^## /gm, '')}`

    text = `<p><a href=#${headingIndex}>${headingText}</p>`
    console.log(text)
  }
}

function convertToHTML(markdownSource) {
  let data = markdownSource.split(/\n\n|^>(?!.)/gm)
    , orig = data.slice()

  for (let i = 0, l = orig.length; i < l; ++i) {
    createContents(data[i], orig[i])
  }
}
```

The input looks like this:

```
## Title 1

## Title 2
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
<p><a href=#item-1>Title 1</p>
<p><a href=#item-2>Title 2</p>
```

But instead I'm getting this:

```
<p><a href=#item-1>Title 1</p>
<p><a href=#item-1>Title 2</p>
```

What am I doing wrong? And how I  can fix it?

Comment: You `let index = 1`  every time you call the function. Why would it become two?

Comment: Might be best to avoid the use of `let` entirely. It's generally considered a best practice to avoid it.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your `index` variable is a local variable and limited to scope of the `if` statement. You should define `index` like this:

```
var index_counter = 1;
function createContents(text, orig) {
  if (orig.match(/^#{2}\s/)) {
    let headingIndex = `item-${index_counter++}`
      , headingText = `${text.replace(/^## /gm, '')}`

    text = `<p><a href=#${headingIndex}>${headingText}</p>`
    console.log(text)
  }
}

function convertToHTML(markdownSource) {
  let data = markdownSource.split(/\n\n|^>(?!.)/gm)
    , orig = data.slice()

  for (let i = 0, l = orig.length; i < l; ++i) {
    createContents(data[i], orig[i])
  }
}
```

> `let` allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the
>   block, statement, or expression on which it is used. This is unlike
>   the `var` keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an
>   entire function regardless of block scope.